# How can I modify an existing Qt stylesheet?

Tags: c++, qt, stylesheet

For example:
if I want to create buttons, which, when pressed, each modify a single aspect of the stylesheet:

- One button can insert a `margin-left` attribute of 10.
- Another button can make the background colors blue.
- Lastly, another button can round the corners.

The trick here, though, is that I don't want to store all the variables and rebuild the style sheet on each button press. I would like, for example, to have a simple:

```cpp
this->setStyleSheet(this->getStylesheet()+"margin-left: 10px:")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the code in main.cpp:

```cpp
QWidget wdg;
QHBoxLayout hlay;
wdg.setStyleSheet("border:2px solid rgb(74, 74, 74);");

QPushButton btn;
btn.setStyleSheet("border-radius:5px;");
btn.setText("Hello");

QPushButton btn2;
btn2.setStyleSheet("background-color: rgb(190, 190, 190);");
btn2.setText("Hello");

hlay.addWidget(&btn);
hlay.addWidget(&btn2);

qDebug()<<btn.styleSheet();

wdg.setLayout(&hlay);
wdg.show();
```

Setting and getting the style sheet works with QString, and so, you can use `+` operator.